# AndroidPdfViewer is not working in KitKat Version

Tags: android-pdf-api, androidpdfviewer

I am Using this Library For AndroidPdfViewer 
https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

```
E/PDFView: load pdf error
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.util.Util.toByteArray(Util.java:36)
        at com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.source.InputStreamSource.createDocument(InputStreamSource.java:37)
        at com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.DecodingAsyncTask.doInBackground(DecodingAsyncTask.java:49)
        at com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.DecodingAsyncTask.doInBackground(DecodingAsyncTask.java:25)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Here I am Getting nullPointer Exception on This Line.

```
inputStream=new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is not a library error, because it's a NullPointer raising due to the null parameter. your PDFViwer is unable to open the file hence it's throwing null pointer exception. you can check you code for the cause. you should follow the best practices to prevent such situations.
Check the connection first, it should not be null. you can check with `?` ternary operator as given below.

```
// InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
// check for the null connection first, it's possible that connection could not be made before opening the InputStream.
InputStream in = (conn != null) ? conn.getInputStream() : null;
```

Comment: But in All Other Versions is AndroidPdfViewer is working Fine with Same code.The Problem is only with KitKat Version.

Comment: Have you Reported the Bug in Repo? Give me the Code Block if Possible.